# Transfer UTM Parameters From One Page To Another/App Url using Firebase Dynamic link

Tags: android, firebase-dynamic-links, utm-tracking

I want to track marketing effort for app, I want to redirect user to my app when he click on download button of web page.

If I call utm link on button click event, then I have to create separate web page for every UTM link.

More explanation :
I created two dynamic link for track different ad campaign.

[image]

Ad campaign redirecting user to my web page, button on web page redirect user to my app. I am calling Dynamic link on Button click for track that event. In this case how to track second dynamic link. [image]

Please suggest any other approach. Goal is track mutliple dynamic link using one page.